# Difference between $A \equiv B \pmod {n}$ and $A \pmod {n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In terms of definition and ideas, what is the difference between saying 
$$A \equiv B \pmod n$$ and $$A \pmod n$$?

Comment: The definition of $a \equiv b\mod n$ is $n$ divides $b-a$. The term $a \mod n$ is the remainder of $a$ when divided by $n$.

Comment: But alternatively, a = b mod n is interpreted as a/n and b/n having the same remainder. 
isn't a/n then a mod (n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying that $$a \equiv b \pmod n$$ means that $a$ and $b$ leave the same remainder after division by $n$. Equivalently, $n \mid b-a$. Examples: $$6 \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \qquad 12 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$$

Saying $a \pmod n$ is just taking the remainder of the division of $a$ by $n$. Examples: $$12 \pmod 5 = 2 \qquad 23 \pmod 4 = 3$$

Comment: And then, this just confirms my previous understanding that there is no difference.
So, $$A=B mod(n)$$ just means that A and B necessarily leaves the same remainder when divided by n?
Whereas, Amod(n) is the remainder when A is divided by n?

Comment: That's what I said.

Comment: And it is only when Amod(n) and Bmod(n) leaves the same remainder,R that we are allowed, under this circumstance, to write $$(A \equiv B)mod(n)?$$

Comment: Writing `\equiv` produces $\equiv$. You meant $A \equiv B \mod n$?

Comment: See edited comment two line above this line

Comment: Since $A \pmod n$ and $B \pmod n$ are the remainders, you can say that: $$(A \pmod n) = (B \pmod n) \iff A \equiv B \pmod n$$

Comment: The quantifiers helped tremendously.

Comment: Parenthesis are our friends! :)

Comment: But how should I make the connection that 
$$(6 \equiv 2)mod(4)$$ because $$6/4$$ and $$2/4$$ leaves the same remainder, $$(6-2)/4$$ does not?

Comment: No, you got it wrong. We have that $6 \equiv 2 \mod 4$ because $4 \mid (6-2)$ (that is, $4 \mid 4$). Alternatively, it is because when we divide $6$ by $4$, we get remainder $2$. When we divide $2$ by $4$, we also get remainder $2$ (because $2 = 0 \cdot 4 + 2$).

Comment: Still lost on this part. Is there any connection between (A-B)/n and A/n and B/n?

Comment: No. Read again the definition that I gave in the answer (and other people too). Attain yourself to it. We're dealing with integers here, things like $(a-b)/n$, etc, could not be integers.

Comment: @help $n \mid (a - b)$ is not the same thing as $(a-b)/n$.

Comment: @Bye_World Very strange. if $$n|(a-b)$$  doesn't this mean there is some  integer c such that $$(a-b)=nc$$?

Comment: @help Yes.  But $/$ is an operator -- it operates on $2$ numbers and then produces another number.  For instance $6/3=2$.  On the other hand $\mid$ defines a relation.  It's more like $=$ or $\gt$ or $\le$.  It can either be true or false.  For instance $2 \mid 6$ but $2 \not \mid 7$ (that line through the $\mid$ symbol means that $2\mid 7$ is FALSE).  Also notice that while $0/0$ doesn't make sense, $0\mid 0$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example, $$\color{red}{10\equiv 1 \pmod{3}}$$ because $3 \mid 10-1=9$ because $3 \times 3 = 9$

However  $10 \pmod{3}$  is the remainder that you get after $10$ is divided by $3$ which is $1$ .

So there is not really a big difference because if $\color{blue}{a \equiv b \pmod{n}}$ then $b$ will be the remainder after $a$ is divided by $n$

But bear in mind that we must have $b \in Z_n$ that is $$\color{green}{ b \in \{1,2,....,n-1\}}$$

Comment: see my  edit , I restrict $b \in Z_n$

Comment: $23  \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$ and so we get $2$ after $30$ is divided by $7$